# Add span after input using ReactDOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create an inline radio/text/input form using `ReactDOM` for React 15, however I'm getting an error when opening my browser:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.
```

The code I'm attempting to use that's throwing this error is as follows:

```
const D = ReactDOM; //react-dom-factories

D.input({
    type: 'radio',
    className: 'stra-on-loss-return-to-base-radio',
    value: 'return_to_base',
    disabled: this.state.active
},  D.span(null, 'Return to base bet'), D.br()),
D.input({
    type: 'radio',
    className: 'stra-on-loss-increase-bet-by',
    value: 'increase_bet_by',
    disabled: this.state.active
},  D.span(null, 'Increase bet by: '), D.input({
    type: 'text',
    ref: 'onLossQty',
    onChange: this.updateOnLossQty,
    value: this.state.onLossIncreaseQty,
    disabled: this.state.active || this.state.onLossSelectedOpt !== 'increase_bet_by' }
), D.span(null, 'x'))
```

---

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dom-factories is ReactDOM in the question
https://pastebin.com/51x23vZy is a copy of the entire file.

Comment: This is a very unconventional usage of react or react dom. Can you give some context as to why you would do this?

Comment: @azium it's a very old system from 3-4 years ago, I'm working on rebasing it with React 15 as don't want to go down the route of JSX; could you give me a better alternative please?

Comment: Is this the actual entire file?

Comment: @azium nope, the entire file can be found here: https://pastebin.com/51x23vZy

Comment: I have a potential answer for you. this is on the web right? are you still able to visit the website (localhost or otherwise?) can you take a screenshot of the elements panel (chrome devtools) and edit your question to include the screenshot?

Comment: @azium I can't since the dom isn't rendered, so nothing is displayed?

Comment: Just like in regular html you cannot have children in an input tag. i.e. `<input type="text"><span>Some content</span></input>` is not valid html so it's not valid in ReactDOM either. Wrap the `input` and `span` in a `div` or something instead.

Comment: I love this question.. It's a portal to ancient times.. ok well the first thing you should do is get the DOM to render which would mean removing a bunch of code. can you delete all of the code in your `render` function that beings with `ReactRadio`? There are two spots in your pastebin. then we can start to add things back one at a time

Comment: @azium I've gone ahead and removed the broken child nodes & here's an example of my DOM : https://pastebin.com/9xDXrbhr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is saying you can't put children inside an `input` element.  You're passing `D.span` and `D.br` arguments as children, in other words you're trying to render this (first half of your example):

```
<input type="radio">
  <span>
    Return to base bet
  </span>
  <br />
</input>
```

HTML doesn't allow `<input>` to have children anyway so React is telling you it's an error.  So you'll need to put the `input`, `span`, and `br` inside a `div`:

```
D.div(
  null,
  D.input({
    type: 'radio',
    ...
  }),
  D.span(null, 'Return to base bet'),
  D.br()
)
```

The corresponding HTML looks like

```
<div>
  <input type="radio" />
  <span>
    Return to base bet
  </span>
  <br />
</div>
```

Or if you don't want a parent `div` or `span` you could wrap them in a  `React.Fragment`.

Comment: Wow that's worked! the only issue I'm having now is my radio buttons don't seem to uncheck? after selecting the un-selected option, they both remain selected

Comment: okay you need to set the `checked` attribute to be `true` or `false` and use an `onChange` handler to update it.  There's an example at https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs

Comment: or you can just use `defaultChecked` if all you care about is form submission.  But if anything else needs to change when they check or uncheck it like enabling or disabling another input, use `checked` and `onChange`.

Answer (score 2):

the file is using the reactDOM component factories. These factories (IIRC) are a wrapper for preconfigured

```
React.createElement(component, props, ...children)
```

calls
so

```
D.input({
  type: 'radio',
  className: 'stra-on-loss-return-to-base-radio',
  value: 'return_to_base',
  disabled: this.state.active
},  D.span(null, 'Return to base bet'), D.br()),
```

`D.span(null, 'Return to base bet'), D.br()` being passed to `D.input` is actually mapped to the `...children` arguments in `react.createElement`

the problem is you cannot pass children to elements like `input` and `img` hence your error